# Jasper email reports - Email addresses - From database

Tags: jasperserver

I'm using Jaspersoft to create reports.

I need these reports to be sent as an email report

I want the email addresses to be read from the database, instead of manually entering them in the report scheduler

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks
Rathi

Comment: Yes, you can write your own code

Comment: Thank you Alex. Can you please tell me where must I start from? Any small example?